# I dont understanding for in order

Tags: python

Im trying to make a binary converter, and I need that the for in read the list in order, but my problem is that the for in dont read the list from an end.

```py
binary = {128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1}

for x in binary:
    print(x)
```

I expect the output to be:
128
64
32
16
8
4
2
1

but the output is:
128
32
64
2
4
1
8
16

will someone explain why it is?

Comment: A set has no order. Did you want an array (list)? `binary = [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer assumes you are using Python)

When you use (with curly braces)

```
{128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1}
```

you define a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#func-set) which is unordered by design.

If you want an ordered [list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#func-list) you can use this (with brackets)

```
[128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks it help alot, im still learning python, and had switched {} and []

Answer (score 1):

Or optionally, you can specify to loop over the sorted set:

```
binary = {128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1}

for x in sorted(binary, reverse=True):
    print(x)
```

[`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#sorted) will create an ordered <strike>list</strike> [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-iterable) from a `set`; sets themselves are unordered.